# Touch ID - How do I make the pin pad/ number pad pop up when i Tap "Enter Password"? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

So I am implementing Touch ID on my app and so far I have everything working out fine besides one thing. When I tap "Enter Password" I would like the number pad/ Pin Pad to pop up to allow the user to enter his password. How would I go about doing that?

****** I am not talking about entering a password inside a textfield!******

Please click the image link for a picture.

https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/iphone6-ios9-passcode-entry.jpg

Thans for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To display "number pad/ Pin Pad to pop up to allow the user to enter his password" when you tap on Enter Password, You have to set LAPolicy type **DeviceOwnerAuthentication** which is newly introduce in iOS9.

```
guard authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) else {

       // No biomatric available Or not enable
       return            
}
```

According to LAPolicy, When you are use DeviceOwnerAuthentication in LAPolicy, you must have to use device passcode to authenticate user.

Comment: I finally found this out earlier today but you are correct! Took hours of research. I upvoted the answer but my points are to low at the moment for it to show. Thanks for posting!